# Android Studio: : app debug:x86 failed to configure C/C++

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Im new in Android Studio and I have this issue with the project.
my windows is new and I never developed on it,

I dont use any other Dev softwares

the LOG:

```
:app debug:x86 failed to configure C/C++
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.CmakeServerExternalNativeJsonGenerator.getProcessBuilder(CmakeServerExternalNativeJsonGenerator.kt:90)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.configureOneAbi(ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.kt:148)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.configure(ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.kt:102)

.............

    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I tried Invalidate cache but not working, I have the latest Android Studio

Comment: Can you add a bit more context about the project you are using? Is it a standard template that fails on first launch? Or have you added some code / made some changes that result to this error?

Based on the error message if I had to guess you are missing / have not linked correctly the required tools for building the project (if you have changed any default configuration).

But without more information about the project it is difficult to help.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was CMake version mismatch on `build.gradle` file and available CMake version

on library/app `build.gradle`'s file, the requested version was 3.10.2 but 3.22.1 was available

your problem might be different so check it out on the build view by clicking on the root item error and scroll to top like this image

[image: Android Studio build view root error]